# Ontario HST rebate: Newly married. Can I change to married status for HST rebate?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate

I recently was married in April 2010.  I received my HST rebate of $100 as a single individual, and my husband didn't receive any. As a couple we would qualify for the $330.  Can I change to the married status or is it based on last year's income tax??

Answer (score 2):

**To receive the higher benefit based on your new status, you'll need to contact the Canada Revenue Agency and inform them of the change**, since they are still assuming you are not married based on your last year's tax return.

Refer to [this question at the Ministry of Revenue's FAQ](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_eligibility.html#Q2).  Quote:

> **What criteria will be used to
>   determine who is eligible for the
>   OSTTB?**
>
> The Canada Revenue Agency (CRA) will
>   use the information you (and your
>   spouse or common-law partner) provide
>   on your income tax return(s) (or
>   statement of world income, if
>   applicable) and your (and your spouse
>   or common-law partner's) Canada Child
>   Tax Benefit (CCTB) information, if
>   applicable, to determine your
>   eligibility for the OSTTB.
>
> **Report to CRA any changes to your
>   status** (e.g., births, death, **marriage**,
>   separation) that happen after filing
>   your tax return.
>
> ...

Refer also to [this other FAQ at the Ministry of Revenue](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_administration.html#Q17).  Quote:

> **What happens if my marital status
>   changes during the year, in 2010 or
>   2011?**
>
> Your OSTTB payment amounts may change
>   if your marital status changes during
>   the year in 2010, or on or before May
>   31, 2011. People who marry, enter a
>   common-law partnership, separate,
>   divorce or become widowed should
>   complete [form RC65, Marital Status Change](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/rc65/README.html),
>   or inform CRA of their new
>   status and the date of the change in a
>   letter. Both spouses (common-law
>   partners) should sign the form or
>   letter. Send the completed form or
>   letter to the [CRA tax centre](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/cntct/tso-bsf-eng.html) in your
>   area.